# Can not access and assign values into composite table of a many to many relationship through front end

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, code-first

I'm trying to develop an ASP.NET MVC application using C# and EF with code-first approach.

I have two classes: `Actors` and `Movies` which have many-to-many relationships (an `Actor` can be in many Movies, a `Movie` can have many Actors).

Everything is working properly, but I can not access the intermediate (MoviesActors) table through a view (this table is generated automatically as a result of the many-to-many relationship between Actors and Movies). I want to access this table so that I could assign the correct primary keys (For example: I want to assign the correct actor to a movie and vice versa) to determine things like "In which movies does a particular actor have played role?" and "What is the star cast of a particular movie?

These are my models:

```
public class Actors
{
    public Actors()
    {
        this.mvz = new HashSet<Movies>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string actor_name { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Movies> mvz { get; set; }
}

public class Movies
{
    public Movies()
    {
        this.actz = new HashSet<Actors>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Movie_title { get; set; }
    public string genre { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Actors> actz { get; set; }
}
```

AS you can see both models have many to many relationship in between them and as a result a third table is generated in database that contains the composite keys.

Everything works properly up to this point, But the issue is that i can not assign values to the composite key table via front end, Although i can assign these values manually from the back-end.

I would like to ask if my approach is correct or not, I mean in a real world application do we have to access the composite key table and assign values, or is there any better approach to solve this issue?

Here is the controller:

```
public ActionResult DataEntry()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(??? mva)
{
    _context.act.Add(mva.act);
    _context.mvz.Add(mva.mvz);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Actors");
}
```

And here is the view:

```
@model Many_To_Many_Relationship_Latest.ViewModel.MoviesActorsViewModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "DataEntry";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

 <h5>Assign Actors to a particular Movie From Here</h5>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Add","MoviesActors"))
{
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a=> a.mvz.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a=> a.mvz.Id, new { @class="forcontrol"})
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(a => a.act.Id)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(a => a.act.Id, new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
}
```

Here is the ViewModel

```
public class MoviesActorsViewModel
{
    public Movies mvz { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Actors> act { get; set; }
}
```

If anyone having expertise in this regard is reading this post, kindly guide me with the correct logic or any other approach that helps me get the result.

Comment: It's generally not a great ideal to pluralize a classes that are not inherently collections of objects.  I would just stick with `Actor` and `Movie` for clarity.  That way you can use public collection properties like `Actors` and `Movies`.

Comment: Adding to Parrish's point, you can rename the 'Actors' class to 'Actor' and rename the collection 'actz' to 'Actors'.. same for movies it's good to note that properties should have a capital letter and private fields should be lowercase

Comment: What does the naming conventions have to do with the result?